# Why do some plants develop a shiny layer that looks like plastic?

Tags: botany

I noticed some plants that look almost as if they were made of plastic and am wondering what and why that is. Here is a sample photo:

[image]

My guess is that this might be some sort of waxy cuticle that protects the plant from either water loss or pests.